# Applying directional derivative operator to a function

Tags: differential-geometry

I'm reading up about the more general definition of directional derivatives, but still in the context of $\mathbb{R}^n$. It goes like this:

> Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ be a **real-valued function** on the manifold $\mathbb{R}^n$ and let $v_p$ be a vector tangent to manifold $\mathbb{R}^n$ at point $p$, that is, $v_p\in T_p(\mathbb{R}^n)$. The number
> $$v_p[f]\equiv\frac{d}{dt}\big(f(p+tv_p\big)\bigg|_{t=0}$$
> is called the **directional derivative** of $f$ w.r.t. $v_p$, if it exists.

Immediately after that there's an exercise:

> Let $v=[2,-1,3]^T$ and $p=(2,0,-1)$. Find $v_p[f]$ where:
>
> a) $f(x)=x$
>
> b) $f(x)=x^2-x$
>
> c) $f(x)=\cos(x)$

I'm a bit confused. Isn't the $v_p$ operator supposed to act on a $\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}$ function in this case? I was under the impression that if we have an $n$-dimensional manifold and a "well-behaved" point $p$ in it such that the tangent space $T_p(M)$ is also $n$-dimensional, then the operator $v_p$ acts on $\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ functions. The above seem like $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$. Am I missing something?

Comment: Could you give the name of the book or source you got these questions from?

Comment: No, you're entirely correct. At least they should have written $f(x,y,z)= \dots$, but I think these are stupid exercises.

Comment: @TedShifrin: Hm, I guess. The book seems pretty awesome at explaining concepts but there are typos and bizarre mistakes like this from time to time. Thanks so much for clarifying!

Comment: @VishnuM It is from the book "A Visual Introduction to Differential Forms and Calculus on Manifolds" from Jon Pierre Fortney. It happens to be a good "good night reading".

Comment: @ShirishKulhari I just ordered the book myself. At first I was a little disappointed, but it seems to be a good reading. Then I came to this point, and was about to ask the exact same question...

Comment: @Cornman: From the perspective of a beginner like me, I like the book! I guess your disappointment might be because it's not the really rigorous, graduate text kind of book? I found it good for self-study or at least developing initial concepts.

Comment: @ShirishKulhari Yes, exactly. When I bought the book, I wanted something more mathematical. But I think I can benefit from this book too, as it gives more emphasis on simple calculation, which you normally do not do. But I feel like that this helps in understanding the concepts.

Answer (score 1):

What you have for the function $f(p+tv_p)$ is a composition
$$\mathbb R\stackrel C\to\mathbb R^3\stackrel f\to\mathbb R,$$
where $C(t)=p+tv_p$ is the parametrization of a line which passes $p$ and goes 
the direction $v_p$. Then $f(p+tv_p)$ is the map 
$$\mathbb R\stackrel{f\circ\ C}\longrightarrow\mathbb R.$$
So
by the Chain's Rule
$$\frac{d(f\circ C)}{dt}\bigg|_t={\rm grad}f|_{C(t)}\cdot C'|_t,$$ 
which at $t=0$ gives you
$$\frac{d(f\circ C)}{dt}\bigg|_{t=0}={\rm grad}f|_p\cdot v_p.$$

Comment: Now by employing a) $f(x,y,z)=x$, b) $f(x,y,z)=x^2-x$,...etc, as Ted's commented, the calculation is simple